# what is meaning and explanation of the scala code required

Tags: scala

```
       val list= (List('a,'a,'a,'a,'b,'b,'b,'c,'c,'c,'c,'d,'e,'e,'e,'f,'a))
       def pack[list](ls : List[list]):List[List[list]] = {
       if (ls.isEmpty) List(List())
       else {
       val (packed, next) = ls span { _ == ls.head }
        if(next == Nil) List(packed)
       else packed :: pack(next)
        }
          }
         println(pack(list))
         }
```

ouput :
               List(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a), List('b, 'b, 'b), List('c, 'c, 'c, 
               'c), List('d), List('e, 'e, 'e), List('f), List('a))

Can anyone explain this code how it works.

Comment: have you tried to debug it? do you have basic knowledge of scala?

Comment: i have given the output !!
I am just learning scala. If you have any Idea on how to master the scala can you please share your ideas.

Comment: yes, by reading scala books and video tutorials on this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span

> "Returns the longest prefix of the list whose elements all satisfy the
>   given predicate, and the rest of the list."

the list here is the ls parameter and ls.head is the first item of the list
The two lists are then assigned to packed (containing the longest prefix) and next which contains the rest. if next is empty the prefix list is returned otherwise there's a recursive call concatenating the prefix list with the result of the recurse